# hackerrank Circular Array Rotation Go Runtime Error

Tags: go, runtime-error

I did solved a hackerrank  problem which is "Circular Array Rotation" using Go
when i run the code it gives me a correct response and when i try to submit the code all the test passes except one and it says  Runtime Error

I tried the failing test localy and it passes 
my code is

```
    package main
    import "fmt"

    func CircularArrayRotation() {
        var n, k, q int

        fmt.Scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &k, &q)
        a := make([]int, n)
        for i := range a {
            fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[i])
        }

        var i int
        for t:=0; t<q; t++  {

            fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
            j := (i - k)
            if j<0 {
                j+=n
            }

            fmt.Println(a[j])
        }

    }

func main() {
 //Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
    CircularArrayRotation()
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: the error is runtime error, and this is all what give me

Comment: [Input](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1884/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1517591126&Signature=2a3G0p2vIJRrBPyjdSXglJAdL2Y%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) and [Expected Output](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1884/output04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1517591124&Signature=qOepybWqGwPx%2Bi5UIlclXsyrZHU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those that want more information you can look here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem

The Input for his failing case is [this](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1884/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1517591180&Signature=2HZ2o7jsYlYhQB8Cr9%2FahCnsoeg%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) and the Expected Output is [this](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/1884/output04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1517591124&Signature=qOepybWqGwPx%2Bi5UIlclXsyrZHU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Your run time error is this:

> panic: runtime error: index out of range
>
> goroutine 1 [running]: main.CircularArrayRotation()   solution.go:22
>   +0x349 main.main()    solution.go:29 +0x20

So your issue is on line 22, where your index is out of range: `fmt.Println(a[j])`

This happens because your code currently cannot handle multiple rotations, so in your code you end up executing the following:

```
fmt.Println(a[-99477])
```

This happens when `i` is `8` and `k` is `100000`

Imagine you had this input:

> n = 3
>   k = 10
>   q = 1
>   i = 2

When you perform `i - k` we get `-8`, we then try to add `n` which gives us `-5` (-8 + 3), then we try to access an index that does not exist. `a[-5]`

If you wish to fix this issue you can do the below (inside spoiler in case you want to work this out yourself):

> put this above your i - k
>  k = k % n

The reason this fixes your code is:

> It works out how many rotations are left after we've fully looped x times. That way we don't have to worry about multiple rotations.

--
As a side note for this challenge there's some interesting stuff you can do with slices for rotating an array using some of the stuff covered here: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/10

Comment: it cannot, because i only do j+=n when j is <0

Comment: Grzegorz Żur : can you explain

Comment: @targat good point, i've added your runtime error to my answer, should help you

Comment: @Pigeon, but i did downloaded the input of the failing test  and run it locally  and it passes

Comment: @targat i've put an explanation of why your code is failing, it can't handle multiple rotations (i downloaded the input also and it fails on locally)

Comment: @targat Put the fix for your code in a spoiler tag, up to you whether you want to work it out yourself or not.

Comment: thank you all for your response. i will try to develop my solution taking this in consideration

Comment: @Pigeon i did added the fix and it pass  all the test. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is correct, however it fails because you only check if j < 0 once. After adding n to it is still negative, so it fails.
Running your code and printing the values when it fails gives:
n: 515, k:100000, q:500, j:-99477

The fix is simple, change your if to a for. This will keep adding n until your index is postive again.

Fixed:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func CircularArrayRotation() {
    var n, k, q int

    fmt.Scanf("%d%d%d", &n, &k, &q)
    a := make([]int, n)
    for i := range a {
        fmt.Scanf("%d", &a[i])
    }

    var i int
    for t := 0; t < q; t++ {

        fmt.Scanf("%d", &i)
        j := i - k
        for j < 0 {
            j += n
        }

        fmt.Println(a[j])
    }

}

func main() {
    //Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
    CircularArrayRotation()
}
```